# Advantages to assigning class values with or without "set" property in methods?

Tags: matlab, class, oop

I have been learning about classes within the MATLAB documentation and noticed that they have recommended two ways to do what seems like the same thing, but I want to know what the difference between them, or advantage to using one over the other, might be. Here, in the methods section of the class, are the two seemingly-identical functions:

```
classdef BasicClass
   properties
      Value
   end
   methods
    function obj = BasicClass(val)
        if (val > 0)
           obj.Value = val;
        else
           error('Value must be numeric')
        end
      end
      function obj = set.Value(obj,val)
         if (val > 0)
            obj.Value = val;
         else
            error('Property value must be positive')
         end
      end
   end
end
```

how does `obj = BasicClass(val)`  differ from using `obj = set.Value(obj,val)` ultimately? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The method `BasicClass` is the constructor of your class. 
Considering your example, evenf if the result will be the same, the difference will be that using the method `set.Value` you will be able to update the parameter `Value` of an existing object whereas calling directly `BasicClass` will create a new object at each function call.